# How to plot streamlines at a desired coordinate

Tags: matlab

I have a 2D velocity field from experimental data and I'm trying to plot the streamlines. This works very well with [streamslice](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/streamslice.html) and [streamline](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/streamline.html), an example of it is here (taken from the Mathworks site):

```
load wind

figure
streamslice(x,y,z,u,v,w,[],[],[5])
axis tight
```

Now, say I want to plot the streamlines that start/go through a certain point `x,y`, say, `x=85` and `y=25`. Is it possible to do that with Matlab? I tried using `streamline` in this way, `streamline(x,y,u,v, 85,25, 0)`, but this gave me an error. It seems it only accepts arrays of starting points, not just one.

Comment: So, do you want just 1 streamline or a set of streamlines in desired coordinates?

Comment: For some reason I can not give starting coordinate in `y`. I can use `x`, and `y` start points freely, bot not `y`. Not sure if a bug or I dont understand something

Comment: @AnderBiguri A set of starting points for the streamlines is also OK, like `(x,y)=(1,1), (5,8), ...` How did you manage to make it work?

Comment: I did not manage to make it work. I can make it work if I lave empty (`[]`) the `y` , but as soon as I put something there, I get some indexing error. Also, remember that you are missing 2 variables in your last line. Its not `streamline(x,y,u,v, 85,25, 0)` its `streamline(x,y,z,u,v,w, 85,25, 0)`